# We're staying away

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=3314).

> So this steak is $72 and if you eat it in one hour you get it for
> free. But look at how gigantic that thing is. Plus you got to eat
> shrimp, baked potato, a salad and bread. The fastest person has done
> it in 4 minutes and 30 seconds. **We're staying away**.

Does 'We're staying away.' mean that they can't break the record of 4 minutes and 30 seconds?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means 'we're not even going to attempt the challenge (to get the expensive steak free)' probably because as it is a very big steak and you have to eat all the other things too, it might make us sick, or be not very much fun, or we think it is greedy and stupid. We are staying away from the challenge.

It could also mean 'we aren't going to the restaurant at all'. The steak is expensive and large and a good restaurant does not need to have silly tricks like this to get customers.